# Class are being linked more than once in target

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, unit-testing, realm

I have two targets `app` and `appTests`. Also I have class `Wine` and framework `Realm` and 'RealmSwift' which are linked to those two targets. There is no exception When I use class `Wine` in traget `app`.

But when I want to run test like

**appTests.swift** (22 lines)

```
import UIKit
import XCTest
import RealmSwift

class appTests: XCTestCase {
func testRealmAdd() {
         NSFileManager.defaultManager().removeItemAtPath(Realm.defaultPath, error: nil)
        let realm = Realm()
        let wine = Wine() // when error occure
        wine.photo = "photo"
        wine.desc = "description"
        wine.raiting = 3.0

        realm.write { () -> Void in
            realm.add(wine)
        }

        let result = realm.objects(Wine)
        print("\(result)")
        XCTAssertTrue(result.count == 1, "There should be one element")
    }
}
```

**Wine.swift** (10 lines)

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

class Wine: Object {

    dynamic var desc: String = ""
    dynamic var photo: String = ""
    dynamic var raiting: Double = 0

}
```

Then an exception appear at line 8 in `appTests.swift`

> RLMObject subclasses with the same name cannot be included twice in the same target. Please make sure 'Wine' is only linked once to your current target.

I already did clear DerivedData and project. Could You suggest where I should look?

**EDIT after nhgrif comment**

Ok it appears that an exception is rising earlier, in line 7. Which is now marked in code thanks to nhgrif.

Comment: Which line is line 8?  This likely doesn't have anything to do with the source code, but instead with how you're linking the frameworks to the projects.

Comment: @nhgrif I add those frameworks like tutorial said https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#getting-started , and then I marked `Realm.framework`, `RealmSwift.framework` and `Wine.swift` as checked for target `appTests` in **Target Membership**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Wine.swift` should only be in `app`, and not `appTests`. Including it in both results in `appTests` having two classes named `Wine` (`app.Wine` and `appTests.Wine`), which is not something that Realm supports. As long as `Wine` is `public` (or in Swift 2.0, `@Testable`), you can access it from `appTests` without including it in the `appTests` target because `appTests` links in `app`.

Comment: Also I have to make public every func and property which will be used in test. What's more I have to add `import app`. I can't wait for Swift 2.0 :)